# How to add headers to a HttpActionContext response without short-circuiting the pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a basic authentication Http filter for my ASP.NET application.

As part of the authentication, I need to add a header to the response.  When my filter is called, the actioncontext.Response is null.  If I create the response, I can add my headers, but it then short-circuits the pipeline, and the actual controller function is never called.

Should I be using a different way to implement my authorisation?

Answer (score 0):

Please use Global AuthenticateRequest and PreSendRequestHeaders event to update response:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    // The AuthenticateRequest event signals that the configured authentication mechanism has authenticated the current request.
    // Subscribing to the AuthenticateRequest event ensures that the request will be authenticated before processing the attached module or event handler.
    public void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // your authenticate code
    }

    public void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // your add heard code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Fan.  I did investigate that idea, but it seemed like the wrong way.  I've managed to wire up an action filter that will generate the header on the way in, and place it in the response on the way out.  It seems like it is the 'correct' way to do it in current versions of ASP.NET.